# How to pass additional parameter to jquery $.(post) callback function?

Tags: javascript

I am writing this code where I am sending a sequence of asynchronous post requests by using a loop. When the callback related with the post request is called I want to use the loop variable which I directly cannot use because of javascript scoping rules. The code is like this:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
$.post(url,requestData,function(data,status,xhr){
// use variable i
}
```

I cannot directly use i due to scoping rules related to callbacks in javascript. So I want to pass 'i' as a parameter to the callback but the documentation says there can be only 3 parameters associated with this callback. Is there any way to pass additional parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable `i` inside the callback if `i` is block scoped. Declare `i` with `let` keyword

```
for(let i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   $.post(url,requestData,function(data,status,xhr){
      // use variable i
   }
}
```

Here's a demo

```js
const $ = {
  post: function(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => callback(123, 'OK', null), 1000);
  }
}

for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
{
     $.post(function(data,status,xhr) {
         // use variable i
       console.log(i);
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using setTimeout here to demonstrate an async task (such as your $.post event).

```js
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000);
}
```

`i` has changed before you get to run your `console.log`.

Instead, you must retain a COPY of the `i` value at the appropriate number.

```js
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  const idx = i;
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(idx);
  }, 1000);
}
```